# Azure AD B2C how to prevent duplicate email address registrations from different applications

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

we are developing custom signin/signup policies with social Idp's and local Account registrations.

We have Application A with 3 extension attributes need to be captured and Application B with 2 extension attributes to be captured which are different from Application A.

same user can register for both the applications.

Problem we are facing now is, we are seeing duplicate email address entries when a user registers from both the applications using the same email address.

Is it possible to prevent duplicates and maintain the attributes in a single profile? (Currently, both application's policy files are different and we are looking for a solution)

Thanks,

Comment: Interesting. Users aren't able to register the same email address more than once. Is this occurring because the same user is registering with a local identity for the first application and registering with a social identity for the second application?

Comment: I hope you seeing a duplicate email but not duplicate email and IDP. Email is possible when the same user registers with a local account and from any social account which is associated with the same email address. In B2C there is an ask and you can vote for this @ https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13214529-azure-ad-b2c-how-to-avoid-validate-duplicate-s.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett --  I chose Facebook Idp to register with Application A and my email address say abc@yahoo.com, and I went to Application B and chose Facebook Idp and used the same email address abc@yahoo.com. After successful registrations from both the applications, I see 2 entries of abc@yahoo.com saying Facebook User

Comment: @RamaKrishna --  I chose Facebook Idp to register with Application A and my email address say abc@yahoo.com, and I went to Application B and chose Facebook Idp and used the same email address abc@yahoo.com. After successful registrations from both the applications, I see 2 entries of abc@yahoo.com saying Facebook User

Comment: @Lucky I didn't see this behavior, can you please more specific about steps you followed (edit your question) or raise a customer request to B2C by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-support. Team will verify your tenant and policies and let you know possibilities.

Comment: Hi @Lucky So the email addresses are same but the Facebook identities are different?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett, yes, it is correct.